# Baseline alignment of absolute child

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I'm trying to build a Unicode table which can compare glyph blackspace between fonts.

My intention is for user-selected fonts on the table; Obviously, fonts have different (unknown) metrics. So—as per the following example—is it possible to align the children's font to the parents' font's baseline *after* absolutely positioning the child glyph objects?

```css
#box{
  display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
  font-size: 72pt;
  /* dimension ref */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#box > span {
  display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
  font-family: serif;
  border: 1px solid #F0F;
}

#box > span > span {
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: red;
  /* alignment ref */
  outline: 1px solid #0F0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span>x<span>x</span></span>
  <span>y<span>y</span></span>
  <span>z<span>z</span></span>
  <span>!<span>!</span></span>
</div>
```

My preferred solution would be pure CSS, but a scan of the available resources indicates that's unlikely. Are font metrics exposed at all to JavaScript, such that I could just calculate a top or bottom margin and shove it in as a CSS variable?

Otherwise, I'm left pulling relative child glyph objects left (read as: towards flex "start") by half their width plus half the parent width? And that gets messy because I'll need per-character adjustments and that's a time-consuming calculation when I'm displaying 10K+ glyphs and the user changes fonts…

---

**EDIT:** As reference, my system uses "Georgia" as `serif` and "Comic Sans MS" as `cursive`. I also am testing initial resulting in Gecko/Firefox, then aligning them to Chromium. Normally this might not matter, but these are areas where different browsers/engines may render with subtle differences. For the above fonts, default baselines in *Word* align as follows:

[image: xyz! inter-font baseline alignment.]

- "Comic Sans" 'z' and '!' should bleed under the baseline, as does right side of the 'x'.
- 'y' actually connects above the baseline
- All glyphs both ascend higher and descend lower than their respective "Georgia" glyph.

Comment: Suddenly realizing SVG may provide a solution, but worried about memory consumption. Will tinker and post results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this.  I've wrapped each "letter" into their own div.  Then set both the first `span` and the child `span` to `position: absolute;` and set both of them to `bottom: 0;` giving them the same baseline.

I also gave the new dives a margin in order to space the letters out a bit. Check out what I did here:

```css
#box{
  display: inline-block;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
  font-size: 72pt;
  /* dimension ref */
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}

#box > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

#box > div > span {
  display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
  font-family: serif;
  border: 1px solid #F0F;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#box > div > span > span {
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: red;
  /* alignment ref */
  outline: 1px solid #0F0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<div><span>x<span>x</span></span></div>
<div><span>y<span>y</span></span></div>
<div><span>z<span>z</span></span></div>
<div><span>!<span>!</span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I obviously can't see your particular combination of generic font types (I'm seeing `serif` as "Georgia" and `cursive` as "Comic Sans MS"). And your engine may differ (I'm using Gekco in Firefox 105.x). Your method comes close but produces interior spans rendering about half an endstop above the baseline. These are similar results to adding `align-items: center` to the exterior spans in my example (which is about half an endstop below the baseline with the same font combo).

Comment: Also, `align-items: baseline` doesn't work because it seems an otherwise-inline object's baseline positioning is destroyed once positioned absolutely?

Answer (score 0):

Set `box position to relative` then control `absolute` children's position with `px` or `%`

```css
#box{
    display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
    font-size: 72pt;
    /* dimension ref */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #box > span {
    display: inline-flex;
          justify-content: center;
    font-family: serif;
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
  }
  
  #box > span > span {
    position: absolute;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: red;
    /* alignment ref */
    outline: 1px solid #0F0;
    bottom: 1%;
  }
```

```html
 <div id="box">
    <span>x<span>x</span></span>
    <span>y<span>y</span></span>
    <span>z<span>z</span></span>
    <span>!<span>!</span></span>
  </div>
```

put them on the side

```css
#box{
    display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
    font-size: 72pt;
    /* dimension ref */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #box > span {
    display: inline-flex;
          justify-content: center;
    font-family: serif;
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  
  #box > span > span {
    position: absolute;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: red;
    /* alignment ref */
    outline: 1px solid #0F0;
    bottom: -1%;
    left:  70px;
    width: 50px;
    
  }
```

```html
 <div id="box">
    <span>x<span>x</span></span>
    <span>y<span>y</span></span>
    <span>z<span>z</span></span>
    <span>!<span>!</span></span>
  </div>
```

EDIT: regarding your comment:

---

for that, I think it will be better to put letters in **one container**, then `position` **both** of them `absolute` with baseline alignment. the following example shows that without any additional positioning, meaning it's the baseline of the font. and you can adjust positioning using `bottom`

```css
#box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size: 72pt;
  /* dimension ref */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 100px;
}

.black {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: underline;
  
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: serif;
  border: 1px solid #F0F;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
}

.red {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="box">

    <div class="black">XYZ!</div>
    <div class="red">XYZ!</div>
   
  </div>
```

Comment: But the characters aren't atop their respective counterpart, which negates the blending effect I need. And on my screen, they're still not baseline aligned.

Comment: In case it was a factor: the pic I added was simply to show the default, unaltered baseline positioning for those two fonts. It wasn't to imply I actually want the glyphs separated; the character pairs _should_ be atop one another on my table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I may have lost the forest for the trees: letter-spacing at `-1em` for the parent glyph seems to avoid the need for absolute positioning of the child glyph while maintaining the original inline baseline. Flex is also unneeded for the glyph parent.

Additional benefit is that the outlines now conform to the individual font dimensions rather than being homogenized by flex and absolute positioning.

(Of note: `mix-blend-mode` is imperative to what I'm trying to accomplish, but doesn't seem to be honored by the snippet console for text, only the box model. So, use your imagination or demo elsewhere. Highlighting the text in the snippet result also demos the intended effect.)

```css
div#box {
  font-size: 72pt;
  letter-spacing: -1em;
  /* box ref */
  outline: 1px solid #F0F;
}

#box > span {
  font-family: serif;
  /* dim ref */
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

span > span {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #0FF;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  /* dim ref */
  outline: 1px solid #0FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span>x<span>x</span></span>
  <span>y<span>y</span></span>
  <span>z<span>z</span></span>
  <span>!<span>!</span></span>
</div>
```

A rare example of `em` doing what I would expect rather than something bizarre.